# converting ascii code into a string, when the ascii code characters is not separated by a comma

Tags: mysql, database, type-conversion, character, ascii

Lets assume i have:

```
 DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE check(     
    )
    set x = 9899100;
    select char(x);
    DELIMITER ;
```

So i was expecting to get 'bcd' as an output but it did not work but when i try:

```
select char(98);
```

then it works and prints out 'a'.
I have int not fixed numbers that can be of any length but surely accurate to be converted from ascii to char but without a separator or anything. Can someone help me how to achieve what i need please.
Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it going to work ever. Just think logically, how should the code knows which numbers are representing 1 character? Tho whole number, or 1 digit, or two digits...
Or may i totally misunderstood your query.

Comment: Exactly.. What is `111111` is it `11 11 11` or `111 111`?

Comment: You totally got it right fra. Yes you are right. Any solution what should i do at this stage?

Comment: Paul Spiegel thats right. My bad.

Comment: Any solution for it?

Comment: Solution? Don't save strings as numbers this way.